# Compile time constants and reference types

Tags: c#

Ok, consider the following code:

```
    const bool trueOrFalse = false;
    const object constObject = null;

    void Foo()
    {
        if (trueOrFalse)
        {
            int hash = constObject.GetHashCode();
        }

        if (constObject != null)
        {
            int hash = constObject.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

`trueOrFalse` is a compile time constant and as such, the compiler warns correctly that `int hash = o.GetHashCode();` is not reachable.

Also, `constObject` is a compile time constant and as such the compiler warns again correctly that `int hash = o.GetHashCode();` is not reachable as `o != null` will never be `true`.

So why doesn't the compiler figure out that:

```
    if (true)
    {
        int hash = constObject.GetHashCode();
    }
```

is 100% sure to be a runtime exception and thus issue out a compile time error? I know this is probably a stupid corner case, but the compiler seems pretty smart reasoning about compile time constant value types, and as such, I was expecting it could also figure out this small corner case with reference types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UPDATE: This question was t[he subject of my blog on July 17th 201](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/07/17/should-c-warn-on-null-dereference.aspx)2. Thanks for the great question!

> Why doesn't the compiler figure out that my code is 100% sure to be a runtime exception and thus issue out a compile time error?

Why should the compiler make code that is guaranteed to throw into a compile-time error?  Wouldn't that make:

```
int M()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

into a compile-time error? But that's exactly the opposite of what you want it to be; you want this to be a runtime error so that the incomplete code compiles.

Now, you might say, well, dereferencing null is clearly undesirable always, whereas a "not implemented" exception is clearly desirable. So could the compiler detect just this specific situation of there being a null ref exception guaranteed to happen, and give an error?

Sure, it could. We'd just have to spend the budget on implementing a data flow analyzer that tracks when a given expression is known to be always null, and then make it a compile time error (or warning) to dereference that expression.

The questions to answer then are:

- How much does that feature cost?
- How much benefit does the user accrue?
- **Is there any other possible feature that has a *better* cost-to-benefit ratio, and provides *more* value to the user?**

The answer to the first question is "rather a lot" -- code flow analyzers are expensive to design and build.  The answer to the second question is "not very much" -- the number of situations in which you can *prove* that null is going to be dereferenced are very small. The answer to the third question has, over the last twelve years, always been "yes".

Therefore, no such feature.

Now, you might say, well, C# does have some limited ability to detect when an expression is always/never null; the nullable arithmetic analyzer uses this analysis to generate more optimal nullable arithmetic code (*), and clearly the flow analyzer uses it to determine reachability. So why not just use the already existing nullability and flow analyzer to detect when you've always dereferenced a null constant?

That would be cheap to implement, sure. But the corresponding user benefit is now *tiny*. How many times in real code do you initialize a *constant* to null, and then *dereference* it? It seems unlikely that anyone would actually do that.

Moreover: yes, it is always better to detect a bug at compile time instead of run time, because it is cheaper. But the bug here -- a guaranteed dereference of null -- will be caught *the first time the code is tested*, and subsequently fixed.

So basically the feature request here is to detect at compile time a very unlikely and obvioulsy wrong situation that will always be immediately caught and fixed the first time the code is run anyways. It is therefore not a very good candidate for spending budget on to implement it; we have lots of higher priorities.

---

(*) See the long series of articles on how the Roslyn compiler does so which begins at http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/

Comment: I find that resharper does a pretty decent job there

Comment: @SebastianGodelet: Excellent point. If a tool like Resharper or FXCOP already does this analysis then let's not duplicate effort by adding it to the C# compiler.

Comment: I would hope that you also consider "how much could it cost the user?" too :)

Comment: @JonHanna, do not underestimate the `savings` that stem from deeper code analysis, potential errors/bugs are much cheaper when caught early

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Thanks for the answer. I obviously understand that a data flow analyzer is expensive, I wasn't pointing towards that. Obviously if the feature I was musing about means time and money then forget it, I agree it's a corner case with no practical use. I was wondering simply *why* it would cost the extra effort. The compiler is smart enough to detect definite assignments, constant expressions so I was wondering if it was able to detect this issue as it currently is but it was simply decided that it was not a feature one would want to have.

Comment: @SebastianGodelet what makes you think I do? Many features have their down-sides though (pretty much any except those that just make things more reliable and/or performant behind the scenes), and I would imagine that's also added to the three questions Eric mentions.

Comment: @JonHanna, sorry I think I did misunderstand your comment, I'm not a native speaker... Yes, your point would be a nice addition

Comment: @SebastianGodelet and I'm not good at expressing myself when restricted to 600 characters. Aw well, another non-native speaker I managed to offend today :(

Comment: "If I had more time, I'd write shorter." -- Mark Twain

Comment: @SebastianGodelet Blaise Pascal was there sooner with "I would have written a shorter letter, but I did not have the time" :)

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Maybe C# can learn a bit from Haskell in this matter?

Comment: @RoopeshShenoy: I'm not following your train of thought. The design of Haskell has heavily influenced the design of C# 3; Haskell expert Erik Meijer was on the C# language design team at the time.

Comment: As you probably already know, Haskell just eliminates a lot of thorny bugs by eliminating "nullreference" (90% of the time at least!) through it's type system and the Maybe monad. As a developer I have to shoot myself in the foot and use something like fromJust to introduce possibility of runtime exception. 

At the same time, you can still have error functions - something that triggers a runtime error - when you especially want it. 

So I think the default should be avoid all runtime exceptions through compile time checks, except if the programmer really really wants it.

Comment: I think code contracts allows a way to do that, but it's again additional code - certain things (avoid nullreference for e.g.) should be default behavior I think. In contrast, all reference types just come as nullable in C#. Even an extension to say "ok, I want all my reference types to be non-null" that can then give me static-time checks would be nice.

Comment: @RoopeshShenoy: Sir Tony is on the record as saying that null references were the billion dollar mistake; I think there is broad agreement that we as an industry could have handled it better across languages and type systems. The problem is that it is quite difficult to get non-nullability into a type system that doesn't have it built in from the start. The SpecSharp Microsoft Research version of C# has non-nullable reference types FYI.

Comment: @EricLippert SpecSharp definitely looks interesting! I think it solves a lot of gripes I have with C# (or Java for that matter!). But I think we could even get that non-null type check in C# via code-contracts; now if we could inject code-contracts aop style in all type declarations at once, that would let me optionally introduce non-null-reference check for currently nullable-types (in my existing codebase) as well, right? I am guessing Roslyn might be of help to achieve something like this.

Answer (score 4):

While unreachable code is useless and does not affect your execution, code that throws an error is executed.  So

```
if (true) { int hash = constObject.GetHashCode();}
```

is more or less the same as

```
throw new NullReferenceException();
```

You might very well want to throw that null reference.  Whereas the unreachable code is just taking up space if it were to be compiled.

Comment: Hmm although plausible I find it kind of hard that someone would want to throw an exception that way

Comment: Which is why most code analysis tools will "suggest" that what you're doing is wrong.  At least I know resharper gives a warning, but no error.

Answer (score 2):

It also won't warn about the following code that has the same effect:

```
throw new NullReferenceException();
```

There's a balance with warnings. Most compiler errors happen when the compiler can't produce anything meaningful from it.

Some happen with things that affect verifiability, or which cross a threshold of how likely they are to be a bug. For example, the following code:

```
private void DoNothing(out string str)
{
  return;
}

private void UseNothing()
{
  string s;
  DoNothing(s);
}
```

Won't compile, though if it did it would do no harm (the only place `DoNothing` is called doesn't use the string passed, so the fact that it is never assigned isn't a problem). There's just too high a risk that I'm doing something stupid here to let it go.

Warnings are for things that are almost certainly foolish or at least not what you wanted to happen. Dead code is likely enough to be a bug to make a warning worthwhile, but likely enough to be sensible (e.g. `trueOrFalse` may change as the application is developed) to make an error inappropriate.

Warnings are meant to be useful, rather than nuisances, so the bar for them is put quite high. There's no exact science, but it was deemed that unreachable code made the cut, and trying to deduce when throwing exceptions wasn't the desired behaviour didn't.

It no doubt helps that the compiler already detects unreachable code (and doesn't compile it) but sees one deliberate throw much like another, no matter how convoluted on the one hand or direct on the other.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you even want that to be a compile-time error? Why would you want code that is guaranteed to throw an exception to be invalid at compile time? What if I, the programmer, want the semantics of my program to be:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    throw new NullReferenceException();
}
```

It's my program. The compiler has no business telling me this isn't valid C# code.